# Play Reactive Mongo Plugin for Play 2.4 and ReactiveMongo 0.13

Tags: mongodb, playframework, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

The latest version of Mongo is 3.6. My project is somewhere in the bronze-age with version 2.6.

We are still at Play 2.4, using the reactive mongo plugin `"org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.11.11-play24"`.

R[eactive Mongo's website states that their driver is compatible](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.1x/documentation/release-details.html#compatibility) with Play 2.3.13 to Play 2.6. It is however, hard to find, which plugin supports which driver.

In general it seems like we can follow the structure `"org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "<<mongo-driver-version>>-play24"`. [However, when I look at the repos](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/reactivemongo/play2-reactivemongo_2.11/), I do not see this library.

**Question:**
What reactive mongo DB and driver versions can be supported by the plugin on Play 2.4

Answer (score 1):

For Reactivemongo, the latest version supporting playframework 2.4 is 0.12.7. This driver version will work with mongodb 3.6 even though it might not provide all the latest functionalities.

If you want to use a newer version of Reactivemongo with play 2.4, you could start from the raw driver and code yourself the functionalities needed to integrate with playframework in your own project. The most important one being the integration in the lifecycle.

Comment: Where is the compatibility of 0.12.7 listed. I could not find this on their site. In the sense, how do I know what is really supported by 0.12.7. It will be best if at least in some sense 3.6 is supported by this driver.